# Failed http request WebApi using Angular

Tags: c#, .net, api, cors, handle

I am trying to connect a service created in .net from angular but I get an error with CORS, I have looked for many links but none have helped me since most of the solutions are for .NET CORE and I am using standard .net .

call from angular:

```
 return this.http.post('http://localhost:50112/api/auth', userdata).toPromise();
```

Api:

```
public class AuthController : ApiController
{
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Auth(User userdata)
    {
        var result = await bllUser.auth(userdata);
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

and this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:50461/api/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I also tried adding the config.EnableCors statement in my webapiconfig file but it tells me that that statement does not exist

[image]

I would appreciate your help, no solution has served me

Answer (score 0):

To use enable cors

Install CORS to the API project "Install-Package Microsoft. Asp. Net. WebApi. Cors".
And change your register method

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
    config.EnableCors(cors);
    // ...
}
```